# Pass by value faster than pass by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I made a simple program in c++ to compare performance between two approaches - pass by value and pass by reference. Actually pass by value performed better than pass by reference.

The conclusion should be that passing by value require fewer clock-cycles (instructions)

I would be really glad if someone could explain in detail **why** pass by value require fewer clock-cycles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void function(int *ptr);
void function2(int val);

int main() {

   int nmbr = 5;

   clock_t start, stop;
   start = clock();
   for (long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
       function(&nmbr);
       //function2(nmbr);
   }
   stop = clock();

   cout << "time: " << stop - start;

   return 0;
}

/**
* pass by reference
*/
void function(int *ptr) {
    *ptr *= 5;
}

/**
* pass by value
*/
void function2(int val) {
   val *= 5;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour of these two functions is not the same, so it's not really a fair comparison...  (Also, you're passing a pointer, not a C++ reference...)

Comment: `function2` does *nothing*, so it can be omitted from the machine code entirely.

Comment: For builtins like int. Pass by value is great. For other things like user defined types or stl containers use pass by reference.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - so you mean the compiler is smart? Then the execution should be close to zero for function2. Actually (I forgot to mention the time: approx 6500 ms for pass by ref. and 5400 ms for pass by value)

Comment: @user2365568 Not exactly smart, but these days they're not quite as stupid as they used to be.

Comment: The compiler could just choose to skip the loop entirely as it does nothing.

Comment: @Cedric H - so what does 5400 ms account for then?

Comment: I don't know. I'm saying that what you are doing is not necesseraly a real test. I could compile the same code with a different compiler, find 0ms and conclude that passing by value is instantaneous.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization (Release build for VS, -O2 or -O3 for gcc)? I got 0 for both functions.

Comment: @jliv902 - no optimization because its not within the scope of the question. I am intersted in how this is handled at the cpu-level (machincode instructions, clockcyckles) - at the fetch-execute level

Comment: where is pass by reference? am i crazy or everyone is crazy?

Comment: @user2365568 The fetch-decode-execute level is the [microcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode) level. Honestly, not even Intel engineers would be able to break it down that far to you on a modern processor. My answer provides an assembly/machine code overview. I'm sure someone could explain the clock cycle count difference, but that's probably as good as you're going to get.

Comment: @texasbruce: You're right...as far as C++ is concerned, there's no "pass by reference" here.  A number of C books use the term to describe passing by pointer, though.  (They can get away with it because C doesn't have references.)  Someone who learned C first gets a little bit of slack; they have a bunch of stuff to unlearn.  :P

Comment: @chao He tagged C++ not C so i think hes talking about C++...

Comment: I would suggest refraining from deprecated C headers (`<time.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`) and `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A good way to find out why there are any differences is to check the disassembly. Here are the results I got on my machine with Visual Studio 2012.

With optimization flags, both functions generate the same code:

```
009D1270 57                   push        edi  
009D1271 FF 15 D4 30 9D 00    call        dword ptr ds:[9D30D4h]  
009D1277 8B F8                mov         edi,eax  
009D1279 FF 15 D4 30 9D 00    call        dword ptr ds:[9D30D4h]  
009D127F 8B 0D 48 30 9D 00    mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[9D3048h]  
009D1285 2B C7                sub         eax,edi  
009D1287 50                   push        eax  
009D1288 E8 A3 04 00 00       call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (09D1730h)  
009D128D 8B C8                mov         ecx,eax  
009D128F FF 15 2C 30 9D 00    call        dword ptr ds:[9D302Ch]  
009D1295 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
009D1297 5F                   pop         edi  
009D1298 C3                   ret
```

This is basically equivalent to:

```
int main ()
{
    clock_t start, stop ;
    start = clock () ;
    stop = clock () ;
    cout << "time: " << stop - start ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Without optimization flags, you will probably get different results.

function (no optimizations):

```
00114890 55                   push        ebp  
00114891 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
00114893 81 EC C0 00 00 00    sub         esp,0C0h  
00114899 53                   push        ebx  
0011489A 56                   push        esi  
0011489B 57                   push        edi  
0011489C 8D BD 40 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
001148A2 B9 30 00 00 00       mov         ecx,30h  
001148A7 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
001148AC F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
001148AE 8B 45 08             mov         eax,dword ptr [ptr]  
001148B1 8B 08                mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
001148B3 6B C9 05             imul        ecx,ecx,5  
001148B6 8B 55 08             mov         edx,dword ptr [ptr]  
001148B9 89 0A                mov         dword ptr [edx],ecx  
001148BB 5F                   pop         edi  
001148BC 5E                   pop         esi  
001148BD 5B                   pop         ebx  
001148BE 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
001148C0 5D                   pop         ebp  
001148C1 C3                   ret
```

function2 (no optimizations)

```
00FF4850 55                   push        ebp  
00FF4851 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
00FF4853 81 EC C0 00 00 00    sub         esp,0C0h  
00FF4859 53                   push        ebx  
00FF485A 56                   push        esi  
00FF485B 57                   push        edi  
00FF485C 8D BD 40 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
00FF4862 B9 30 00 00 00       mov         ecx,30h  
00FF4867 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00FF486C F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
00FF486E 8B 45 08             mov         eax,dword ptr [val]  
00FF4871 6B C0 05             imul        eax,eax,5  
00FF4874 89 45 08             mov         dword ptr [val],eax  
00FF4877 5F                   pop         edi  
00FF4878 5E                   pop         esi  
00FF4879 5B                   pop         ebx  
00FF487A 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
00FF487C 5D                   pop         ebp  
00FF487D C3                   ret
```

**Why is pass by value faster (in the no optimization case)?**

Well, `function()` has two extra `mov` operations. Let's take a look at the first extra `mov` operation:

```
001148AE 8B 45 08             mov         eax,dword ptr [ptr]  
001148B1 8B 08                mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
001148B3 6B C9 05             imul        ecx,ecx,5
```

Here we are dereferencing the pointer. In `function2 ()`, we already have the value, so we avoid this step. We first move the address of the pointer into register eax. Then we move the value of the pointer into register ecx. Finally, we multiply the value by five.

Let's look at the second extra `mov` operation:

```
001148B3 6B C9 05             imul        ecx,ecx,5  
001148B6 8B 55 08             mov         edx,dword ptr [ptr]  
001148B9 89 0A                mov         dword ptr [edx],ecx
```

Now we are moving backwards. We have just finished multiplying the value by 5, and we need to place the value back into the memory address.

Because `function2 ()` does not have to deal with referencing and dereferencing a pointer, it gets to skip these two extra `mov` operations.

Comment: +1 for detailed answer. I'll look into this in due course of time and maybe accept it :-)

Comment: this is only true when there is no copy-constructor or destructor for the value you are passing by value

Answer (score 34):

Overhead with passing by reference:

- each access needs a dereference, i.e., there is one more memory read

Overhead with passing by value:

- the value needs to be copied on stack or into registers

For small objects, such as an integer, passing by value will be faster. For bigger objects (for example a large structure), the copying would create too much overhead so passing by reference will be faster.

Answer (score 15):

Imagine you walk into a function and you're supposed to come in with an int value. The code in the function wants to do stuff with that int value.

Pass by value is like walking into the function and when someone asks for the int foo value, you just give it to them.

Pass by reference is walking into the function with the address of the int foo value. Now whenever someone needs the value of foo they have to go and look it up. Everyone's gonna complain about having to dereference foo all the freaking time. I've been in this function for 2 milliseconds now and I must have looked up foo a thousand times! Why didn't you just give me the value in the first place? Why didn't you pass by value?

This analogy helped me see why passing by value is often the fastest choice.

Answer (score 12):

To some reasoning:
In most popular machines, an integer is 32bits, and a pointer is 32 or 64bits

So you have to pass that much information.

To multiply an integer you have to:

Multiply it.

To multiply an integer pointed by a pointer you have to:

Deference the pointer.
Multiply it.

Hope it's clear enough :)

---

Now to some more specific stuff:

As it's been pointed out, your by-value function does nothing with the result, but the by-pointer one actually saves the result in memory. Why you so unfair with poor pointer? :( (just kidding)

It's hard to say how valid your benchmark is, since compilers come packed with all kind of optimization. (of course you can control the compiler freedom, but you haven't provided info on that)

And finally (and probably most important), pointers, values or references does not have an speed associated to it. Who knows, you may find a machine that is faster with pointers and take a hard time with values, or the opposite. Okay, okay, there is some pattern in hardware and we make all this assumptions, the most widely accepted seems to be:

Pass simple objects by value and more complex ones by reference (or pointer) (but then again, what's complex? What's simple? It changes with time as hardware follows)

So recently I sense the standard opinion is becoming: pass by value and trust the compiler. And that's cool. Compilers are backed up with years of expertise development and angry users demanding it to be always better.

Answer (score 9):

When you pass by value, you are telling the compiler to make a copy of the entity you are passing by value.

When you are passing by reference, you are telling the compiler that it must use the actual memory that the reference is pointing to.  The compiler does not know if you are doing this in an attempt to optimize, or because the referenced value might be changing in some other thread (for example).  It has to use that area of memory.

Passing by reference means the processor has to access that specific memory block.  That may or may not be the most efficient process, depending on the state of the registers.  When you pass by reference, the memory on the stack can be used, which increases the chance of accessing cache (much faster) memory.

Finally, depending on the architecture of your machine and the type you are passing, a reference may actually be larger than the value you are copying.  Copying a 32 bit integer involves copying less than passing a reference on a 64 bit machine.

So passing by reference should only be done when you need a reference (to mutate the value, or because the value might be mutated elsewhere), or when copying the referenced object is more expensive than dereferencing the necessary memory.

While that last point is non-trivial, a good rule of thumb is to do what Java does:  pass fundamental types by value, and complex types by (const) reference.

Answer (score 4):

Passing by value is often very quick for small types since most of them are smaller than the pointer on modern systems (64bit). There may also be certain optimizations done when passed by value.

As a general rule, pass builtin-types by value.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the compiler probably realized that the result of the multiply wasn't being used in the pass-by-value case and optimized it out entirely. Without seeing the disassembled code it's impossible to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Quite often executing 32 bit memory manipulation instructions is slower on a native 64 bit platform, because the processor has to run 64 bit instructions regardless. If it is done correctly by the compiler, 32 bit instructions get "paired" at the instruction cache, but if a 32 bit read is executed with a 64 bit instruction 4 additional bytes are copied as filling and then discarded. In short, value being smaller than pointer size does not necessarily mean it's faster. It depends on the situation and on the compiler, and should absolutely not be taken into consideration for performance except for composite types where the value is definitely larger than the pointer by a magnitude of 1, or in cases where you need the absolute best performance for one particular platform without regards to portability. The choice between passing by reference or by value should depend only on whether or not you want the called procedure to be able to modify the object passed. If it's only a read for a type smaller than 128 bits, pass by value, it's safer.